# Integreation Method In Dr with 3 Sources

Tags: kalman-filter, imu, navigation, gps, dead-reckoning

I'm searching a navigation method to find my location while dead reckogning (gps signals jammed) with an imu and gsm based navigation results.
In short i have 3 sources:

- Gsm Based Navigation ( gives lat lon data at @5hz, around 100m accuracy)
- Imu(gyro+accelerometer)
- GPS Receiver

There are filters like kalman, complimentary etc. but many use this methods when they have 2 source (gps/imu)in my case i have 3. What is simplest way to integrate gsm based pos and imu data in dr and should i use a filter or not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use a filter. You need to adjust to the noises. If you can design or know the state space models of the agent and the sensors then KF is the easiest to use.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you give a simple  model for begining.